# Degree character (°) encoding/decoding

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

I am on windows platform and I use Python 3. 
I have a text file which contains degree characters (°)

I want to read the whole text file, do some processing and write it back with the performed modifications. Here is sample of my code :

```
with io.open('myTextFile.txt',encoding='ASCII') as f:
for item in allItem:
    i=0
    myData = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((n,1)))
    for line in f:

        myRegex = "(AD"+item+")"
        if re.match(myRegex,line):
            myData.loc[i,0] = line
            i+=1
    myData = myData[(myData.T != 0).any()]
    myData = myData.append(pd.DataFrame(["\n"],index=[myData.index[-1]+1])) 
    myData = myData[0].map(lambda x: x.strip()).to_frame()
    myData.to_csv('myModifiedTextFile.txt', header = False, index = False, mode='a', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ', encoding = 'ASCII')
```

However I am getting unicode errors although I tried specifying encoding/decoding :

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 512: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Text files are written with a specific character encoding. If you don't know what it is then you can't read it properly. Can you find out which encoding the author used? (This is a general weakness of CSV as a format. You need the encoding, header, quoting, …, …. along with the bytes.)

Answer (score 1):

`ascii` is not very useful here, since it only knows 128 characters, the ones you can find in [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Notice there is no degree sign in that table. I am unsure what the actual encoding of your file is – Unicode and commonly used Windows code pages (1250/1252) have the [degree sign at `0xB0`](https://unicodelookup.com/#%C2%B0/1).

I assume in your file, there is a degree sign at position 512 and it is causing the error. If this is the case, you need to be more specific with your `encoding` argument. Figure out which code page / encoding was used to save the file. Confirm this by looking up the code page and finding the degree sign at `0xE9`.

If there is a different character at position 512 ("é" is a good candidate), then simply specify an encoding like `cp1250`, `cp1252`, or `cp1257`.

Comment: thanks, this is useful, and unicode makese sense, as Python tells it's 0xb0. But now how do I read the file?

Comment: @Vincenzooo If you are asking how to adapt code similar to the original question, it is the `encoding` argument that needs to change, e.g. `io.open("foo.txt", encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: thanks, this is what I was asking as I was not sure in which function to put the argument.